# Tips for Akilon Wastes map?

Tags: starcraft-2

A bunch of the guys I work with have been playing Starcraft 2 - we are mostly Silver/Gold level players and are having a friendly competition of 1v1s. The rule is that in a best of 3 format the first game is always played on the [Akilon Wastes](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Akilon_Wastes) map.

Any tips on features specific to that map?

- For example, as a Terran player it is difficult to sneak reapers in to the main base as the jump up point is quite close to the ramp.

Comment: Let me know how it works out for you JonathanJ

Comment: Won my sudden death match last night 2-1, there's 4 players left now... Got a TvZ matchup next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diamond / Master Terran here:

First of all, this is not a Reaper map! As you explain, the cliffs are not suited for such an attack at first hand. The only real good thing you can use a Reaper too, is if your enemy goes for a FE - then you can try to deny it!

The map is good for either:

- 2 / 3 rax stim / combat shield push. And expand behind it! (pull back if theres a wall off, or the enemy have 2 or more canons or bunkers and or siegetanks - enter the mid game from here)
- Widowmine drop versus Protoss or Zerg. And expand behind it! (drop one or two at the prim. mineralline, and 1 at the NE versus Zerg)
- FE. 10 min. timing with bio and 1/1 upgrades with stim and shields +
  2 medivacs. (versus Zerg and Protoss) Take advantage of your possibilities to drop and push at the entrance!
- Banshee harras versus a Terran. And expand behind it! Kill-list 1. Workers 2. Marines 3. Supplydepots 4. Tech. (add-ons etc.)
  (based on my own experience - so not saying its the best sollution)

It is a fairly short map, keep that in mind.

A fast expansion in to a bio and tank build is also pretty good, as your tanks can wrech havock on the enemys NE.